# Rails: Can I exclude entries from all queries?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am at the end of the development of a Rails app.

I now discovered that I when I do a query in the Car table, I almost never want to find the condemned cars. They have a "true" in the condemned column.

The problem is that my app is littered with different queries to the Car table, and I really don't want to go though my app and find them all.

Is there a way to, in the model put `where.not.condemned` in front of all queries made to the table? Without having to change any of the queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`default_scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-default_scope) method in `Car` model:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { where.not(condemned: true) }
  # ...
end
```

You can also create SQL view and set in as [`table_name`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name) of your `Car` model (but this way you would get read-only model).